# Deformed new leaves on my bilberry (european blueberry) plants

Tags: diagnosis, shrubs, container-gardening

I have some bilberry plants (european blueberry, Vaccinium Myrtillus) growing in containers on my balcony, and I just noticed that new leaves are deformed and discolored (a bit more yellow that the rest of the plant).

Some images:

[image: blueberry deformed leaves 1]

[image: blueberry deformed leaves 2]

[image: blueberry deformed leaves 3]

Some more context:

- The soil has a Ph of approx. 4.5 (according to the vendor)
- It has been very sunny and hot in the last days (more than 25° C ambient temperature, perhaps more than 30 on the balcony)
- The blueberries are under direct sunlight from early in the morning to about 4pm
- I am watering lightly with distilled water and vinegar (1ml/l) once every few days if it doesn't rain. The solution should have a Ph of around 4
- Last week I have inoculated the roots with [ericoid mycorrhiza](https://www.symbiom.cz/en/p-4-rhodovit)

Can please someone help? Should I fertilize/water more?

Thank you.

EDIT:

The crinkled new leaves seem to grow up healthy and overall the plants are doing great.
[image: bilberry flowers]

Comment: I am surprised: where I live, v. myrtillus is growing wild in the forests, but never in full sun, always in dappled shade?

Comment: In the Alps I've always seen it growing in full sun in large colonies, albeit with a lower temperature than 25C..

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen for 2 different reasons.
When I buy plants from a nursery that uses synthetic fertilizers and I use organic.
And when I take them outside in the spring.
If you're watering every few days with vinegar your probably getting too acidic.
These 2 links may help. I've used baking soda on my plants forever.
I don't mean any harm, I use vinegar to kill weeds.
Vinegar, dawn dish soap and sugar is better than roundup.

https://www.fieldnotesbystudioplants.com/houseplants/why-does-my-plant-have-a-wrinkled-leaf

https://balconygardenweb.com/baking-soda-uses-in-the-garden-baking-soda-for-plants/